# Deserialize a file with multiple objects without knowing no of objects

Tags: java, deserialization

I have to de-serialize a serialized file and store the objects into List. Serialized file is already created. I don't know the no of objects. So how should I read all objects in file n store in List structure...I mean how reach at the end of file?

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following should work:

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("path/to/file"));
while (input.available() > 0) {
    Object anObject = input.readObject();
    objects.add(anObject);
}
```

Note that you will only be able to do this successfully if you have access to the original java classes whose instances were serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Read in the file, line by line, checking for EOF. Then deserialize (or store as string) and add to a list.

```
 List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String nextLine = "";
    while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      sb.append(nextLine);
      //Object obj = deserialize(sb.toString());
      list.add(obj);
```

Comment: A serialised file contains binary data. It can't be effectively parsed with a Scanner.

Comment: Fair point, changing to BufferedReader